# upload different types of files with laravel

Tags: php

I've been trying to load files for several days without success.
if I fill in my form and click on submit, keep this error: Whoops! There were some problems with your input.The contenu must be a file of type: jpeg, png, jpg, zip, pdf .
please help me find my error.
here is my code:

My view:

```
<form action="{{ route('course_element.store') }}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="index">Index:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="index" class="form-control" placeholder="Index">
                        </div>
                        <input type = "hidden" id = "course_id" value="{{ $course->id }}" name= "course_id">  
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="format">Format</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="format" id="format">
                                <option>Text</option>
                                <option>Image</option>
                                <option>Audio</option>
                                <option>Video</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="purpose">Ojectif</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="purpose" id="purpose">
                            <option>Vocabulaire</option>
                            <option>Grammaire</option>
                            <option>Conjugaison</option>
                            <option>Prononciation</option>
                            <option>idioms</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group"> 
                        <label for="contenu">Contenu</label>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="contenu" id="contenu" placeholder="Contenu" aria-describedby="fileHelpId" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <small id="fileHelpId" class="form-text text-muted">Help text</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="content" id="content" rows="3" placeholder="Contenu"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                     </form>
```

route:

```
Route::resource('course_element', 'Course_elementController');
```

It is the 'contenu' field which must contain pdf, video, docx, images, etc. this is my controller:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    { 
        $course = $request->input('course_id');  
        $courses = Course::all();
        $request->validate([
            'index'=>'required',
            'format'=>'required',
            'purpose'=>'required',
            'contenu'=>'nullable|required|mimes: jpeg, png, jpg, zip, pdf | max: 2048',
            'content'=>'required',
            'course_id'=>'required'
        ]);
   
        Course_element::create($request->all());
        $fileName = time().'.'.$request->file->extension();  
   
        $request->file->move(public_path('storage/'), $fileName);
      
       return redirect()->route('course.show')
                       ->with('success','course element created successfully.')
                       ->with('contenu',$fileName);
    }
 
    public function show(Course_element $course_element)
    {
        //
        $courses = Course::all();
        return view ('course_element.show', compact('course_element', 'courses'));
    }
```

migration:

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('course_element', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('index');
            $table->string('format');
            $table->string('purpose');
            $table->string('contenu');
            $table->string('content');
            $table->unsignedInteger('course_id')->nullable(); 
            $table->foreign('course_id')->references('id')->on('course')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');  
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();

           
        });
    }
```

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: hey there, as far as i know you have to add the property "enctype" to the form tag and not the input.

Comment: I tried to correct it by putting enctype in the form tag but I still get the same error!

Comment: I could have corrected this error by deleting spaces like this 'contenu'=>'nullable|required|mimes: jpeg,png,jpg,zip,pdf | max: 2048' instead of that contenu'=>'nullable|required|mimes: jpeg, png, jpg, zip, pdf | max: 2048'.
but I get another error: Call to a member function extension() on null

Comment: I was able to solve the problem it was necessary to put this :
        $fileName = time().'.'.$request->file('contenu')->extension();  
        $request->file('contenu')->move(public_path('storage/'), $fileName);
 instead of that:
        $fileName = time().'.'.$request->file->extension();  
        $request->file->move(public_path('storage/'), $fileName); 
thank you for the help